# How to send message with RFH2 format?

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq, mq-visual-edit

#### Question

I need to inject messages in IBM MQ with JMeter.

Format should be RFH2. I need to set `Format` field to empty and also change content of the header.

Which kind of JMeter object should I used to do that?

Can you help me please? Thanks a lot.

#### Update n°1

Thank to @DmitriT answer I'm able to send message in queue.

However, it seems that header content is not put in the header but before the message. Please find below an example:

**Server logs with message sent with MQ Visual Edit**

*Header*

```
 2020-04-21 11:07:59.913 DEBUG 48093 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] 
 c.b.i.c.listeners.AbstractAgiListener    : Receive message on MQ with header : {someargs, 
 jms_destination=queue:///myqueue, someargs, Sender=mysender, someargs, jms_type=mcd://jms_byte,
 someargs}
```

*Message*

```
 <Document ...>...</Document>
```

**Server logs with message sent with JMeter**

*Header*

```
 2020-04-21 11:07:59.913 DEBUG 48093 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] 
 c.b.i.c.listeners.AbstractAgiListener    : Receive message on MQ with header : {someargs}
```

*Message*

```
 RFH ¨ÿÿÿþ        ¸ <mcd><Msd>jms_bytes</Msd></mcd> 8<jms><Dst>queue:///myqueue</Dst>
<Pri>0</Pri></jms>    <usr><Sender>mysender</Sender></usr><Document ...>...</Document>
```

Any idea how to solve it please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The "JMeter object" you should use is [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

1. Download the relevant version of the [com.ibm.mq.allclient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient/) library (with dependencies) and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the libraries up
3. Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test Plan
4. Create the message according to your requirements and publish it to the queue. Reference code:

   ```
   import com.ibm.mq.MQAsyncStatus
   import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage
   import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions
   import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager
   import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC
   import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants
   import com.ibm.mq.headers.MQRFH2

   def mqProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>()
   mqProps.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN')
   mqProps.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414)
   mqProps.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, '192.168.99.100')

   def qManager = 'QM1'
   def queueName = 'DEV.QUEUE.1'


   def qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, mqProps)
   def openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
   def queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions)

   def pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions()
   pmo.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE
   def message = new MQMessage()
   def rfh2 = new MQRFH2()
   rfh2.setEncoding(CMQC.MQENC_NATIVE)
   rfh2.setCodedCharSetId(CMQC.MQCCSI_INHERIT)
   rfh2.setFormat(CMQC.MQFMT_STRING)
   rfh2.setNameValueCCSID(1208)
   rfh2.setFieldValue('your', 'data', 'here')
   rfh2.write(message)

   queue.put(message, pmo)
   queue.close()

   MQAsyncStatus asyncStatus = qMgr.getAsyncStatus()
   log.info('Successfully published: ' + asyncStatus.putSuccessCount + ' message(s)')
   ```

References:

- [MQRFH2 class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030950_.htm)
- [Handling IBM MQ message headers with IBM MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030880_.htm)
- [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer! So, based on the code you provided, need I to create `producer` and `consumer`? Or just creating the message and posting it til get the response of the server is suffisant?

Comment: With this code I'm able to send the message in the queue. Thank you a lot. Just one last thing. It seems that the RFH2 content is put before the message and not in the header. I updated my question with details. Thank you again.