# MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033' while trying to retreive a message from a queue

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I try to catch a message from a queue. Note that the message has a `xml` content.

However, an exception is throw in the block `catch (MQException e)` while the message is correctly received by the queue.

> MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'

Please find below code used:

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC
import com.ibm.mq.headers.MQRFH2
import com.ibm.MQException

def mqProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>()
mqProps.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, 'mychannel')
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, myport)
mqProps.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, 'myhost')

def qMgr = new MQQueueManager('myqueuemanager', mqProps)
def openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF

def gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions()
gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT + CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING

def queue = qMgr.accessQueue('myqueue', openOptions)
MQMessage receiveMsg = null
boolean getMore = true
while(getMore) {
    receiveMsg = new MQMessage()

    try {
        // get the message on the queue
        queue.get(receiveMsg, gmo)
        def rfh2 = new MQRFH2(receiveMsg)
        def strucLen = rfh2.getStrucLength()
        def encoding = rfh2.getEncoding()
        def CCSID = rfh2.getCodedCharSetId()
        def format = rfh2.getFormat()
        def flags = rfh2.getFlags()
        def nameValueCCSID = rfh2.getNameValueCCSID()

        def b = new byte[receiveMsg.getDataLength()]
        receiveMsg.readFully(b)
        System.out.println("Data: " + new String(b))
        queue.close()
   } catch (MQException e) {
      if (e.completionCode == CMQC.MQCC_FAILED && e.reasonCode == CMQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) {
         // No message - loop again
      }
      else {
         log.info("MQException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage())
         log.info("CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode)
         getMore = false
      }
   } catch (IOException e) {
      log.info("IOException:" + e.getLocalizedMessage())
   }

}
```

Could you please help me to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I am assuming there is at least one message in the queue when get was called. Also put "def gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions() gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT + CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING 
" inside the while loop because GMO gets initialised when get call returns. So subsequent get calls will use the GMO intialised from previous call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I put code you mentioned inside while loop, i'm facing same issue.

Comment: Are there messages in the queue?

Comment: I supposed yes because I'm able to see the messag through a dedicated web interface. But maybe that the message is consumed by the program of the application, is it possible?

Comment: Can't confirm because I don't know anything about the web application you are using.

Comment: To be honest I don't know anything also. I just need to catch the message but if the application consume the message it is not there...

Comment: Reason Code of 2033 (MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) is normal.  It means the application has consumed all messages on the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> def openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT |
>   MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF

There is no reason to open the queue for both input and output.  Also, you should include MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING.

> def qMgr = new MQQueueManager('myqueuemanager', mqProps) def queue =
>   qMgr.accessQueue('myqueue', openOptions)

I strongly recommend that you use UPPERCASE, queue manager and queue names.  Also, it is an IBM Best Practise.

> queue.close()

The close method should be called in the finally clause otherwise you could get memory leak.

I posted ***MQTEST12L.java*** (fully functioning) many times to StackOverflow.  You can get it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771413/i-need-to-browse-through-ibm-mq-and-get-a-particular-type-of-message-and-then-re/57776736#57776736).

Use MQTest12L as an example on how to correctly code a Java application to get messages from a queue.